# Loading a FXML into borderpane center

Tags: javafx, center, fxml, borderpane

Good evening guys,

I am playing around with JavaFX. The aim is to load a prepared fxml into the center element of a borderpane on button click. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```html
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Coden/Eclipse%20Workspace/Project%20Tango001/bin/application/Page1Gui.fxml:8

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at application.MainGUIController.LadeCenterNeu(MainGUIController.java:19)
 ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Page1GUIController.java
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 71 more
```

Please find my simple code as follows:

Main.java:

```js
//*** Main.java

package application;
 
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  try {
   BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainGUI.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
   scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

MainGui.fxml:

```html
//*** MainGui.fxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane id="maincontent" fx:id="maincontent" maxHeight="344.0" maxWidth="600.0" minHeight="344.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainGUIController">
   <top>
      <Pane prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00567F;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="24.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#LadeCenterNeu" text="Button" />
         </children></Pane>
   </top>
   <left>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="98.0" style="-fx-background-color: #33677F;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <Pane id="MainGUICenter" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4CC5FF;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="169.0" layoutY="92.0" text="Initialer Inhalt" textAlignment="CENTER" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
   <right>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #33677F;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </right>
   <bottom>
      <Pane prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00567F;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

MainGuiController.java:

```html
//*** MainGuiController.java

package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class MainGUIController {
 
 @FXML
 Pane maincontent;
 
 @FXML
 private void LadeCenterNeu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
  maincontent.getChildren().clear();
  maincontent.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Page1Gui.fxml")));
  System.out.println("Load!");
 }
 
}
```

Page1Gui.fxml:

```html
//*** Page1Gui.fxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="425.0" prefWidth="545.0" style="-fx-background-color: #111111;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Page1GUIController.java">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="-169.0" layoutY="-176.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Label layoutX="259.0" layoutY="204.0" text="Inhalt 2" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Page1GuiController.java:

```html
package application;

public class Page1GUIController {

}
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys,

I finally made it ;-)

The following code made my day:

```
public void LoadDashboardFXML(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    StackPaneMain.getChildren().clear();
    StackPaneMain.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Dashboard.fxml")));
    StackPaneMain.setLayoutX(0);
    StackPaneMain.setLayoutY(0);
}
```

I've simply added

```
@FXML
StackPane StackPaneMain;
```

in the controller class of the Main.java (fx:id).

Now, the StackPane gets cleared first and then the fxml gets loaded.

Answer (score 3):

The `fx:controller` attribute needs the fully-qualified class name. I.e. in Page1GUI.fxml you need `fx:controller="application.Page1GUIController"`

(Note: I didn't read over all your code: there may be other errors. But that is the cause of the error you posted.)

Answer (score 1):

This will help others.
If u wanna to load fxm in the center of border pane

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("prepared.fxml"));
        borderPane.getChildren().remove(borderPane.getCenter()); //remove existing fxml from center.
        try {
            borderPane.setCenter(fxmlLoader.load());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```